# SELECT same row as repeated result from mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like

```
+------+----------+
| id   | location |
+------+----------+
|    1 | TVM      |
|    2 | KLM      |
|    3 | EKM      |
+------+----------+
```

And I have an array of id like **[1,2,1,3,1]**. I need to get the result as

```
+------+----------+
| id   | location |
+------+----------+
|    1 | TVM      |
|    2 | KLM      |
|    1 | TVM      |
|    3 | EKM      |
|    1 | TVM      |
+------+----------+
```

I am already tried WHERE IN like conditions but no luck.

Answer (score 3):

A `where` statement cannot multiply the number of rows.  It can only filter rows out.  You want a `join`:

```
select tl.*
from tablelike tl join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 1 union all
      select 3 union all select 1
     ) n
     on tl.id = n.n;
```

Note:  if you are already generating the list via a query or from a table, then use that for the query rather than passing the list out of the database and then back in.

Comment: @Gordon Is there any other idea, without split the condition array  **[1,2,1,3,1]**.

Comment: I need it on the same order

Comment: @Love my fate: to have a guarantee an order, you need an ORDER BY on the outer query. You could have the inline view return another column...  `(SELECT 1 AS n, 1 AS s UNION ALL SELECT 2, 2 UNION ALL SELECT 1,3 UNION ALL SELECT 3,4 ...)`  and then add `ORDER BY n.s` on the outer query.

Comment: @Lovemyfate . . . Your question is *explicitly* about repeating rows and makes no mention of the ordering.  SQL result sets are unordered by default, unless you include an explicit `order by` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Don't be foolish. I am already post my expected result.

Comment: @Lovemyfate . . . Repeat:  Tables and result sets in SQL are unordered unless explicitly specified with an ordering.  Your question does not specify an ordering.

Comment: @GordonLinoff my sample output mention the ordering

Answer (score 0):

You could also return this result with a query like this; this uses a separate SELECT to return each occurrence of row with id=1.

```
  ( SELECT id, location FROM mytable WHERE id     IN (1,2)
    ORDER BY id
  )
  UNION ALL
  ( SELECT id, location FROM mytable WHERE id     IN (1,3)
    ORDER BY id
  )
  UNION ALL
  ( SELECT id, location FROM mytable WHERE id     IN (1)
    ORDER BY id
  )
```

Following a similar pattern, the result could be obtained by combining the results from five SELECT statements, each returning a separate row. That would probably be a little simpler to achieve from a small array, e.g.

```
$glue = ") ) UNION ALL
  (SELECT id, location FROM mytable WHERE id IN (";

$sql = "(SELECT id, location FROM mytable WHERE id IN (" 
     . implode($glue, $myarray)
     . ") )";
```